# How can I send someone an early version of my game made in clickteam fusion 2.5?

Tags: distribution, clickteam-fusion

I'm currently in the process of making my first game and have a pretty sturdy prototype, but I don't know how to send it out to select people. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. I don't think there are many people here who use ClickTeam Fusion. You may want to try searching/asking on [their forums](http://community.clickteam.com/forum.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used ClickTeam Fusion, but if it simply like other programs, and if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iHJjncN9AVc) video is not outdated, you should be able to export your game and build it into either an [iOS](http://www.clickteam.com/ios-export-module), [Android](http://www.clickteam.com/android-export-module), [Flash](http://www.clickteam.com/flash-export-module), or [HTML5](http://www.clickteam.com/html5-export-module) format.

If you are making a PC game, then Flash or HTML5 work, otherwise, you could use iOS or Android respectively.

#### TO EXPORT:

- Click on `Tools` on the menu bar and make sure `Preferences > General > Exporters` is set to your preferred exporting file system, whether it be Android, iOS, Flash (SFW), or HTML5. If you're not sure go with SFW.
- If you set it to be Android, you will probably have to download the Android SDK and figure out where your JDK directory is, but a quick Google search will clear up both.
- In any case, once you are done with that and made sure all the settings are to your liking, you can proceed to click on `File` on the menu bar and head to `Build > Application` where you will then choose where to build your application. Create a folder on the desktop or wherever you want, and build it in there.
- Wait for a bit, and viola, your game has been exported.

#### TO SEND TO OTHERS:

- Upload your file to a file sharing site such as [Mediafire](http://mediafire.com/), [Mega](https://mega.co.nz/), [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), or [Google Drive](https://www.google.com/drive/).
- Send the person you wish to send the game to the link.
- The person downloads the file, and if it is SFW, they will have to have [Flash Player](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) to run it, otherwise, they can either run it in their typical browser (HTML5) or in their respective phones (iOS or Android).
- If you are feeling particularly open, you could always upload your code to [GitHub](https://github.com/) and there anyone can download your code, or help with it's development such as editing it or fixing it. (With your consent of course).

Comment: Will that then create the game, or allow me to send it to specific people?

Comment: It will create the game, and then you can use any file sharing website such as Mediafire, Dropbox, or Mega to share the game to other people.

Comment: Is there a way to send it to people without releasing it?

Comment: What do you mean without releasing it? Do you want to send the source code of the game?

Comment: Without officially releasing it yes.

Comment: Uhh? I have no idea what you mean. There is no "release" button. If you export your game, you can play the game, but no one else can unless you send it to them. So the only way you can release your game is to put it online for people to download. But if you want to send the source code (the unplayable game) and only the code, just upload your games files and send the link to someone.

Comment: So I can export it then send it to someone and once they've given me feedback I can continue to work on it until I decide to release it for the public? Is that correct?